# Using SQL Server DTS Package to Conditionally Insert / Update Rows in Destination Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, dts

I want to create a DTS Package to pull data from an Oracle table into a SQL2K 
table.  How can I insert rows that are not already in the SQL2K table and 
update rows that already exist in the SQL2K table?

I guess I could truncate and repopulate the entire table or create a 
temporary table and then do updates/inserts from the temp table into the 
destination table.

Is there any easier way using DTS?

Thanks,

Rokal

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a DTS package using two data driven query tasks: one for the inserts and one for the updates. The data driven query tasks are a bit of a pain to use, but they work. I've also done this (a "merge") in sql server 2000 with an AS/400 database using a dynamic t-sql. You'd write a t-sql script that outputs psql and runs it againt a linked server to the Oracle database.

UPDATE:
A DTS "data driven query task" **will** let you insert|update data from the sql server connection in DTS to an oracle server connection in DTS w/o a temp table or a linked server.

Update2; here's some more info on what I mean:
http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3315951

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933507(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Booji Boy:

Yes, I could create a database link and write two data driven queries.  I was hoping there was a way without using linked servers or staging tables.

Comment: I founds some additional information on data driven query tasks in DTS. Let me know if it helps -  I might be able to dig up (or make) and send you an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you keeping the same primary key values?

If you are you have a number of options,  some versions of SQL support the MERGE statement which will update or insert just like you require.

Or you can write your own.

Something along the lines of loading all the rows into a staging table in your SQL database and row by row checking for the existence of your primary key in your main SQL table. If the key exists update the row and if not insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the primary key values in the source and destination will match.

I was hoping to accomplish this task without the use of a temporary (staging) table.

Also, I am using sql server 2000 so the MERGE statement is not available.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way with TSQL to do a INSERT or UPDATE in the same statement, but you could very easily do it in two statements (as you mentioned above).

Statement 1:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.WhateverTable 
WHERE WhateverTableID IN (SELECT WhateverTableID FROM MySource)
```

Statement 2:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.WhateverTable 
SELECT * FROM MySource
```

Also, is there any reason why you don't want to use a temp table?

Comment: Timothy Khouri:

Your method would require a database link correct?

Comment: merge behaves like an insert or update in one statement in tsql

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.WhateverTable WHERE WhateverTableID IN (SELECT WhateverTableID FROM MySource)
```

It might be pretty slow, use join instead:

```
Delete a
from firstTable a join secondTable b on a.id = b.id
```